# Making a clicked image have a style

Tags: html, css

At the moment I have 3 images and when hovered they have a border around them, what I want is when the user clicks the image the hovered style remains on that image, I tried using :active but to no avail.

Here is the CSS code:

```
.portfolio-image{
border: 1px solid #e8ebef;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
height:150px;
margin-bottom:20px;
max-width:100%;
position:relative;
width:150px;
}

.portfolio-image:hover{
border:1px solid #123;
box-shadow:none;
}
```

and the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N22Jc/

Comment: `<img src="/" onClick="this.style.border = '1px solid red';">`

Comment: Tried it, didn't work

Comment: Try in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/NL4Sj/).

Comment: That works but when I add a second image and click both of them the red border stays on both of them and doesn't switch to the active one?

Answer (score 0):

:active only stays in effect when the user has the mouse pressed down on the element.

You will need to use JavaScript to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, CSS:

```
fieldset{
border:0px; padding:0px;
}
img.style1{
border: 1px solid #e8ebef;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
height:150px;
margin-bottom:20px;
max-width:100%;
position:relative;
width:150px;
}
img.style2{
border:1px solid #123;
box-shadow:none;

}
```

JavaScript (head):

```
`function changeStyle(id, newClass){
        document.getElementById(id).className = newClass;
        }

        function changeOther1(newClass){
        document.getElementById("i1").className = newClass;
        }
}
```

HTML:

```
`<fieldset class="radios"><label for="one" class="label_radio">
                                <img src="yourimage.jpg" id="i1" class="style1" onclick="changeStyle(this.id, 'style2');">
                                <input name="number" id="one" value="" type="radio" /></label></fieldset>
```

I didn't test the code, but you get the idea. (I used radios, because I assume you want these to be used in a form?)

Comment: Want it to be used in a portfolio

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give the `focus` on an element by clicking on it , that doesn't usually take focus unlike form elements, You need to add the `tabindex` attribute and set it to `0` in order to have a `div` or an `img` to be able to take the focus and use in CSS `:focus`.

In your fiddle , you draw a border on a `div` that holds a link that holds an image. the `div` has no `tabindex`.

When you click this box , this is the link that catch the click, not the div nor the image , and off you go and `:focus` is not usable like this.

---

You could use `:target` if structure allows you to do so via CSS, [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/N22Jc/3/).

---

*instead using `nth-child(x)` as in demo , you could use single ids on your boxes to select them clearly and not mind in wich number position they stand.*

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jQuery solution if you're interested and here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/NL4Sj/)**</kbd>

```
<img src="/" class="item" alt="Image">
<img src="/" class="item" alt="Image">
<img src="/" class="item" alt="Image">
<img src="/" class="item" alt="Image">
```

---

```
img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.active {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

---

```
<script>
  (function($) {   

    $('.item').click(function() {
      $(this).addClass('active').siblings('.item').removeClass('active');
    });

    /* Requires jQuery UI
    $('.item').click(function() {
      $(this).switchClass('item','active',300).siblings('.active').switchClass('active','item',300);
    }); 
    */

  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

***Note:** Put script just before the `</body>` tag.

Of course to be able to use jQuery you must include jQuery library in the `<head>` section of your HTML document like below

```
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- And if you want to use script above which requires jQuery UI -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

***Note:** You can also download jQuery & jQuery UI libraries and instead CDN versions you'll be able to load local versions. [Download jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js) - [Download jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/resources/download/jquery-ui-1.10.4.zip)

If you decide to use local versions. download them, put them in the root folder of your site and include them like below

```
<head>
  <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Also you can put the libraries in folder e.g. `js` or `scripts` and then just change path to your local libraries versions

```
<head>
  <script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

That's it, if you decide to use jQuery and if you have additional questions, ask ;)

Comment: I tried it but when I used it I added removing a box shadow which is on the actual image and it doesn't remove it and also when I click the next image the style stays on the previous image

Comment: @Gareth just look at the Fiddle, everything works, I don't understand you about `box-shadow`. Do you want to remove `box-shadow` property from the active image? If so I've updated the Fiddle with that option.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try it out now

Comment: That's because in your code images are in separate div's and they are not siblings anymore, I've updated the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/Sb3YR/1/) with solution for your case ;)

Comment: Cool that works, however the box shadow still exists